# PERN movie app when fetching api got error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"

Tags: reactjs, api, express, deployment

I am fetching api in signing up but can't get valid JSON format.

It works just fine in my local, after deployed in railway I got error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

This is the error in the console

[image]

Below is my Front end code

```
fetch("https://react-rmdb-backend-production.up.railway.app/signup", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(user => {
        if (user.id) {
          setUser({
            id: user.id,
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email
          });
          navigate("/");
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Server

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const knex = require("knex");
const app = express();

const { handleSignup } = require("./controllers/signup");
const { handleLogin } = require("./controllers/login");

const db = knex({
  client: "pg",
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  // ssl: {
  //   rejectUnauthorized: false,
  // },
});

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).json("success"));

app.post("/login", (req, res) => handleLogin(req, res, db, bcrypt));

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => handleSignup(req, res, db, bcrypt));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
  console.log(`server is running on PORT: ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

Back end code

```
const handleSignup = (req, res, db, bcrypt) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;

  if (!email || !username || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json("Something went wrong");
  }

  const saltRounds = 10;
  const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds);

  db.transaction((trx) => {
    trx
      .insert({
        hash: hash,
        email: email,
      })
      .into("login")
      .returning("email")
      .then((loginEmail) => {
        return trx("users")
          .returning("*")
          .insert({
            username: username,
            email: loginEmail[0].email,
          })
          .then((user) => {
            res.json(user[0]);
          });
      })
      .then(trx.commit)
      .catch(trx.rollback);
  }).catch((err) => res.status(400).json("unable to sign up"));
};

module.exports = {
  handleSignup,
};
```

I've tried to add a proxy in both front end and back end package json file but doesn't work.

How do I get json response from my back end?

Thank you

Comment: As per the error API doesn't respond as expected. Also i think the data didn't reached to the backend, that's why backend didn't respond. Did you try your API of login and signup on postman?

Comment: Hi Varun, I've tried postman and got the same error with the response "Internal Server Error", could you give any advice to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Christy can you please print the result of req.body to make sure anything getting from frontend. 
  const { username, email, password } = req.body; 
console.log("UserName-",username,"Email-",email,"password",password)
if you get anything just lemme know.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Varun, I put the console.log("UserName-",username,"Email-",email,"password",password) in my signup back end file and the error is 400 with "unable to sign up", I guess now I am connecting with my back end? however I still don't know how to make it work...

Comment: yupp but still you didn't get the data to backend... now try to console.log("Body Request",req.body)

Comment: Hey @VarunKaklia you're right! I use postman to print the req body it's like what I put, and my front-end network tab payload exists the data as well...
Is there anything I misunderstood?

Comment: Did you receive the data in the backend req.body console.?

Comment: Yes, I did. Hey Varun, I don't know how to thank you for your time to help me understand this issue. I finally deployed my app successfully! The main mistakes I should avoid the next time:

1. Use res.json instead of res.send
2. Add the homepage in my backend package json file
3. The database in railway is different from Heroku, the varchar should be replaced with text in railway <-- this is the main reason why this app fails
Thank you so much for your help, really appreciated that! 